# Airplane with banner in a windy day

Tags: aircraft, relative-motion, equilibrium

Will the banner of this airplane be always in the proper direction if the airplane flies in any direction on a windy day?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than User58220's answer, I'm reading a lot of nonsense here.

When you fly an airplane (I and many other people on this site do), when you are cruising in the air, you center the rudder.

The plane has no awareness of the movement of the air mass over the ground (wind).
The plane has a vertical stabilizer (tail) which causes it to point into its relative wind, which is entirely unrelated to the motion of the air mass over the ground.
If it is towing a banner, that also flows in a line with the airplane.

If you deflect the rudder pedals, that pushes the tail of the plane left or right, causing the relative wind to blow more against one side of the airplane.
You don't do that to compensate for wind over the ground (except during landing and takeoff, when you don't have a banner).

The rudder is used in turns to compensate for adverse aileron yaw, during takeoff to compensate for asymmetric propeller thrust, and during landing to keep the nose lined up with the runway in a crosswind.

If you do anything with the rudder in cruise, you are not doing it to compensate for air movement over the ground.

EDIT: adding some educational videos:

[*Crosswind landing technique.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaMWpa-tk-A)

[*More than you wanted to know about banner towing.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufXXU6ur9Ac)

Better late than never: Suppose the air mass is simply not moving, but the ground underneath *is* moving (with respect to the air).
The plane just flies in the still air, banner and all, irrespective of what the ground's doing.

*However*, if it is needed to fly from airport A to airport B, as User58220 pointed out, that's a *navigation* problem, not an aircraft-operation problem.
It is necessary to turn the plane to a direction such that it will arrive at the place where airport B will be when both the plane and the airport get there.
This is called the [*wind triangle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_triangle) problem, and there is a simple tool to help solve it, called an [*E6B*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6B).

Further edit: I almost forgot that when I first started using the Microsoft Flight Simulator, the plane wouldn't go where I pointed it, which made it very hard to land. It would always drift off center.
Later I learned a fundamental difference between cars and planes.
Cars go where they are *pointed*.
Planes go where they are *carried*.
There's always some sort of wind, so the way you get where you're going is by looking at the *ground* to see where you're being carried.
If you are going to the right of where you want to go, you adjust your heading to the left, and vice versa.
You *never* do it by pointing the plane at your destination, except in a general sense.
I only mention this because not having that understanding could have led to the OP's question.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, the term "crosswind" refers purely to an angle between the true wind direction and the ground track, and ***not*** to an angle between the relative wind and the aircraft axis?

Comment: @User58220: You got it.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey With your last edited-in analogy, you seem to be entering slightly difficult territory. The reason is that this analogy looks to _also_ work for _accelerating_ ground in stead of _accelerating_ air. This would be troublesome. (I'm having a little difficulty with my articulation of this idea, but I hope you get my point. Pls confirm.) But for constant velocity  air/ground it is fine (of course).

Comment: @aufkag: Generally you assume that winds are more or less constant (at a particular location and altitude), that you get from a [*winds aloft*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winds_aloft) forecast. If your route is long enough that there will be changes, you solve it by breaking up the route into shorter "legs". It's not a super-precise science.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey That is not my point. The moving-ground-analogy doesn't work physically if the moving is not a constant velocity. It may _invite_ the nonsense that you found on this page. Because then momentum suddenly _is_ relevant.

Comment: @aufkag: in reality, it's not an issue. The only time you see sudden changes in wind speed is if you encounter low-level wind shear (like if there are big trees near the runway, or an inversion). *Vertical* changes, on the other hand, are quite common, making the ride bumpy. Near a thunderstorm, they are dangerously severe. Needless to say, you're not even flying near those, let alone towing a banner.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, so you are saying no matter in what direction airplane is going and in what direction wind speed is (relative to the earth): *pilot always sees wind is blowing in the direction of head to the tail*

Comment: @richard: Right. If the pilot cannot see the ground, like if she is in a cloud, there is no way to tell how fast the air is moving over the ground or in which direction (unless they have a way to tell motion w.r.t the ground). Like if my airspeed is 100, but my GPS or DME says my ground speed toward my target is 60, that tells me I have a headwind component of 40. But without the electronics or ground view, there is no way to tell. Any more than you can be aware of rotational speed of the earth, or orbital speed through space.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, one more thing: doesn't this depend on the type of airplane? for propeller planes which move by pushing air back your answer is correct but not for jets which need not to push air back so they can move in any direction relative to wind. Is this correct?

Comment: @richard: Play with paper airplanes. Buy a balsa wood glider for a couple dollars and fly it. Get a copy of [*Stick and Rudder.*](http://www.amazon.com/Stick-Rudder-Explanation-Art-Flying/dp/0070362408) Take an introductory flight lesson. [*Read this site.*](http://www.av8n.com/) Learn about flight first-hand. Words will not be enough.

Answer (score 6):

If a plane is flying without any rudder input, then the banner will always fly straight behind the plane, with nose-tail-banner in a straight line, no matter what the speed or direction of the plane and/or wind.  The only thing that affects the plane and banner is the flow of air over the control surfaces.  How would the banner know that there was wind blowing?

Forget about taxiing planes and crabbing into the wind on final approach.  These all change the problem by adding the frame of reference of the ground.

A pilot doesn't need or have a ***wind speed meter***.  A pilot doesn't need one, only an air speed indicator.  The navigator would ***love*** to have a wind speed meter, because the navigator is the one that has to worry about ground speed and course made good...

Comment: +1 This is definitely true if the freestream is uniform. Even with no rudder input though, a vertical climb through wind shear could cause a non-zero sideslip angle.

Comment: you conveniently disregard frame of reference to the ground because you don't consider preexisting airspeeds (winds). once they come into play there must be rudder input to maintain bearing, and the towed banner will deflect relative to the fuselage because it has no rudder and is basically hinged to the fuselage at a point far from its own center of pressure.

Comment: @gregsan Please explain "bearing". Naively (me!), it could mean four things. 1) compass direction of flight, 2) direction of flight to fixed point on earth, 3) compass direction of nose, 4) direction of nose to fixed point on earth.

Comment: direction of motion not orientation. the nose can be pointed off bearing (and so a different point on the earth, as will happen in crosswind) while the aircraft still heads to the original fixed point. but this requires a rudder. another way to look at a towed banner is that it is effectively a rudder with zero tension in the flying cables...which I must admit is just another way of describing a wind vane..

Comment: @gregsan But if there is say a 100 km/h 90 degree cross-wind, wouldn't that simply mean that the airplane has a sideways component to its velocity that is also 100 km/h? Why would there be tension on the rudder? Or why would there need to be such tension?

Comment: 100k wind has different effect on the fuselage than the towed banner because of different masses involved. the banner's center of pressure is also it's center of gravity because of the symmetry of the rectangle. basically wind pushes the flag at its center causing it to torque at the point it attaches to the plane. the plane's cross sectional area from the side is not symmetrical, but is biased towards the tail. this means any side wind will act at a point off the plane's cg, closer to the tail, causing torque around the plane's own cg--not just translational motion.

Comment: for stability reasons flying craft including rockets, have center of pressure behind the cg so their natural tendency is for the rear end to fall in line behind the cg (like a wind vane). this is why rudders are behind rather than in front...

Comment: @gregsan You seem to be assuming that the wind suddenly picked up or changed otherwise, whereas I would assume (for this question) that the wind always was there.

Comment: a constant crosswind must be countered by sustained rudder angle otherwise the aircraft rotates until there is no crosswind (it becomes headwind) and then the banner has no reason to be deflected...so it cannot be said that the aircraft can be flown in any direction on a windy day and still maintain neutral banner angle. it can only fly parallel to the wind--other directions require rudder, which the banner does not have and so will deflect accordingly.

Comment: @gregsan Well, I'm not an authority, but for me that settles it. You are wrong and this answer is perfectly correct. The airplane isn't connected to the earth in any way (unlike a sailing boat). It will not rotate from some direction in a fixed and pre-existing wind unless it was rotating to begin with.

Comment: @aufkag A falling plane will fall nose down because like gregsan explained, they are like wind vanes, and WILL rotate until they align with any windspeed not due to their own motion from thrust.

Comment: @Hoby No need to bring in gravity. Sailboats experience the sea as well as the wind. The sea provides the connection with the earth. Flying planes are only connected with the air/prevailing wind.

Comment: @Hoby Let me give you this to think about. An aircraft with a top speed of 500 km/h can fly perfectly in a constant head-wind of 700 km/h. _It will not turn its nose around._ (It will go the wrong way, i.e. backwards, relative to the earth, but that's not the issue.)

Answer (score 3):

The banner is basically a wind vane while the aircraft can resist torque by using its rudder. Even without using the rudder the torque on the craft due to angled wind speed will be lower than the torque on the banner due to the difference in masses.

[image]

Both @user58220 and @Gregsan give valid responses but with relevance to the question I think it is fair to say the banner cannot possibly be always straight regardless of flight conditions. The slant angle no matter how small can be measured according to the formula given by Gregsan, and of course the picture above says a lot.

Comment: Could you clarify (for me; I really don't know), how aircraft fly from A to B? Do try to keep the craft aligned (pointing the nose towards B) with using rudder or do they point slightly into the wind without using rudder?

Comment: @aufkag:  a pilot would typically do a calculation based of the ground course desired, the planes best speed through the air and the anticipated speed and direction of the wind, to obtain the direction to point the plane, and the speed over the ground he could expect.  The plane would point in this direction without constant rudder input.